# L2TP / IPSec couldn't look up L2TP VPN gateway IP address (CentOS 7)

Tags: vpn, centos-7, ipsec, networkmanager, l2tp

I'm trying to connect to VPN from CentOS 7. I have network-manager-l2tp installed (1.2.10). The output I'm getting:

```
Mar 18 23:46:43 localhost NetworkManager[4790]: <info>  [1552949203.6892] vpn-connection[0x561eebea6120,3e1960f9-b5d6-4d39-aa78-0adbe74360b5,"vpn.test.net",0]: Started the VPN service, PID 13659
Mar 18 23:46:43 localhost NetworkManager[4790]: <info>  [1552949203.7015] vpn-connection[0x561eebea6120,3e1960f9-b5d6-4d39-aa78-0adbe74360b5,"vpn.test.net",0]: Saw the service appear; activating connection
Mar 18 23:46:43 localhost NetworkManager[4790]: <info>  [1552949203.7094] vpn-connection[0x561eebea6120,3e1960f9-b5d6-4d39-aa78-0adbe74360b5,"vpn.test.net",0]: VPN connection: (ConnectInteractive) reply received
Mar 18 23:46:43 localhost NetworkManager[4790]: <warn>  [1552949203.7420] vpn-connection[0x561eebea6120,3e1960f9-b5d6-4d39-aa78-0adbe74360b5,"vpn.test.net",0]: VPN connection: failed to connect: 'couldn't look up L2TP VPN gateway IP address '
Mar 18 23:46:43 localhost NetworkManager[4790]: <info>  [1552949203.7436] vpn-connection[0x561eebea6120,3e1960f9-b5d6-4d39-aa78-0adbe74360b5,"vpn.test.net",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopped (6)
Mar 18 23:46:43 localhost NetworkManager[4790]: <info>  [1552949203.7449] vpn-connection[0x561eebea6120,3e1960f9-b5d6-4d39-aa78-0adbe74360b5,"vpn.test.net",0]: VPN service disappeared
```

My output from networkmenager-l2tp and strongswan

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror-pl.kielcetechnologypark.net
 * epel: ftp.arnes.si
 * extras: ftp.man.poznan.pl
 * updates: mirror-pl.kielcetechnologypark.net
Installed Packages
Name        : NetworkManager-l2tp
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 1.2.10
Release     : 1.el7
Size        : 423 k
Repo        : installed
From repo   : epel
Summary     : NetworkManager VPN plugin for L2TP and L2TP/IPsec
URL         : https://github.com/nm-l2tp/network-manager-l2tp
License     : GPLv2+
Description : This package contains software for integrating L2TP and L2TP over
            : IPsec VPN support with the NetworkManager.
```

strongswan:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror-pl.kielcetechnologypark.net
 * epel: ftp.arnes.si
 * extras: ftp.man.poznan.pl
 * updates: mirror-pl.kielcetechnologypark.net
Installed Packages
Name        : strongswan
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 5.7.2
Release     : 1.el7
Size        : 4.0 M
Repo        : installed
From repo   : epel
Summary     : An OpenSource IPsec-based VPN and TNC solution
URL         : http://www.strongswan.org/
License     : GPLv2+
Description : The strongSwan IPsec implementation supports both the IKEv1 and IKEv2
            : key exchange protocols in conjunction with the native NETKEY IPsec
            : stack of the Linux kernel.
```

And config file from /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections

```
id=vpn.test.net
uuid=3e1960f9-b5d6-4d39-aa78-0adbe74360b5
type=vpn
autoconnect=false
permissions=user:hvk:;

[vpn]
gateway=vpn.test.net:1194
ipsec-enabled=yes
ipsec-esp=3des-sha1!
ipsec-gateway-id=vpn.test.net:1194
ipsec-ike=3des-sha1-modp1024!
ipsec-psk=*****
mru=1400
mtu=1400
password-flags=0
user=my_login
service-type=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.l2tp

[vpn-secrets]
password=*****

[ipv4]
dns-search=
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
method=auto
```

And uname -a:
Linux localhost.localdomain 3.10.0-957.5.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Feb 1 14:54:57 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

EDIT:
Solution.
Check selinux and disable that :) pretty easy solution.
Thanks for try help Andy.

Answer (score 0):

`gateway=vpn.test.net:1194`

You are receiving a DNS lookup error. I would carefully check to make sure that whatever domain you have on this line is properly resolved by DNS.

Comment: No, its a placeholder. Its a corporate VPN so i cant share address.

Comment: Can you make sure you can run `nslookup <actual domain name>` from command prompt/terminal? You only need the domain name part, e.g. `nslookup vpn.test.net`.

Comment: Does it work if you type in the IP address instead of the domain name? This is a temporary fix. If it works, I would go back to trying to figure out why the service is unable to look up the gateway IP.

Comment: Looking at similar questions, this could also be an issue with authentication. There is an option for Point-To-Point Encryption (MPPE) that may need to be enabled.

Comment: I add MPPE and same output :/
VPN connection: failed to connect: 'couldn't look up L2TP VPN gateway IP address '. On Windows 10 address, login and password work. Only on CentOS is problem :/